# Laravel how to get sum price for domain prices table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-relations

I am using Laravel 7.0.

My `domain_prices` table has `price`, `duration`, `addPrice` columns.

I created `DomainPrice` model.

`Domain price` for specific duration is `price + addPrice`.

But for 5 years duration, I need to sum all `prices` and all `addPrices` for `1, 2, 3, 4, 5 years`.

I set custom attribute to get `totalPrice` as following:

```
public function getTotalPriceAttribute()
{
   return $this->price+$this->addPrice;
}
```

I wanted to make another custom attribute to get `sumPrice` as following:

```
    public function getSumPriceAttribute()
    {
        $sumPrice = 0;
        $prices = $this->where('Duration', '<=', $this->Duration)->get(); // I removed domain filter query here.
        foreach($prices as $price)
        {
            $sumPrice += $price->totalPrice;
        }

        return $sumPrice;
    }
```

But this didn't return exact results.
Please teach me with fancy approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you used the wrong variable here when you sum your $sumPrice. you should change `$subPrice` in `foreach` loop to `$sumPrice`

```
public function getSumPriceAttribute()
{
    $sumPrice = 0;
    $prices = $this->where('Duration', '<=', $this->Duration)->get(); // I removed domain filter query here.
    foreach($prices as $price)
    {
        $sumPrice += $price->totalPrice; // change $subPrice to $sumPrice
    }
    return $sumPrice;
}
```

Comment: Oh Yes, Actually I used subPrice, I noticed I wrote it wrong, so I tried to change it to sumPrice when I post here. So this won't work.

Comment: Ok, I found issue. That was another typo. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it helped